# React testing library fireEvent.click not working

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to basically just change a counter and show that the value has changed. I am doing this with `getByTestId` so that could be the problem ?

Here is my component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    const [count, setCounter] = useState(0)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                div
                <div
                    onClick={() => setCounter(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}
                    data-testid="addCount"
                >
                    +
                </div>
        <div data-testid="count">
          {count}
        </div>
                <div
                    onClick={() => setCounter(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}
                    data-testid="minusCount"
                >
                    -
                </div>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the test I am trying to run:

```
describe('State is managed correctly', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<App />)
    const add = getByTestId(`addCount`)
    const count = getByTestId(`count`)

    it('count starts at 0', () => {
        expect(count).toHaveTextContent("0")
    })


 it('count added, value should be 1', () => {
        fireEvent.click(add)
        expect(count).toHaveTextContent("1") // error count is still 0
    })
})
```

Comment: You shouldn't save state across tests like this, you're going to shoot yourself in the foot.  You should run `cleanup` before each test run, remount the component, and manipulate the state only in the way you want to change it for that test.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you can't really "manage" state in react-testing-library like I was hoping. Also seems like from reading the docs are you aren't supposed to either.

Here is my solution:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react'

import App from '../src/App'

afterEach(cleanup)

describe('App component loads correctly', () => {
    const { container } = render(<App />)
    const { firstChild } = container
    test('renders correctly', () => {
        expect(container).toHaveTextContent(`Learn React`)
    })

    test('first child should contain class "App"', () => {
        expect(firstChild).toHaveClass(`App`)
    })
})

describe('State is managed correctly', () => {
    it('count starts at 0', () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<App />)
        const count = getByTestId(`count`)

        expect(count.innerHTML).toBe("0")
    })


 it('should add 1 to count', () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<App />)
        const count = getByTestId(`count`)
        const add = getByTestId(`addCount`)

        fireEvent.click(add)
        expect(count.innerHTML).toBe("1")
    })

    it('should minus 1 from count', () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(<App />)
        const count = getByTestId(`count`)
        const minus = getByTestId(`minusCount`)

        fireEvent.click(minus)
        expect(count.innerHTML).toBe("-1")
    })
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `testing-library` and in my case I had:

```
fireEvent(myElement, new MouseEvent('click'));
```

I added `{bubbles: true}` changing it to:

```
fireEvent(myElement, new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true }));
```

and it worked! It seems the event should bubble to work. The same happens with native `dispatchEvent`, need bubbles to work:

```
myElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("click", { bubbles: true }));
```

Answer (score 3):

Every time you need to verify something to need to re-run the query.  `const count = getByTestId('count')` sets `count` to the initial value, so you need to tell it to look up the count again after firing the event.

```
it('count added, value should be 1', () => {
  fireEvent.click(add)
  count = getByTestId('count')
  expect(count).toHaveTextContent("1") // error count is still 0
})
```

Comment: So I did `expect(getByTestId('count')).toHaveTextContent("1")` and now getting an error of `Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="count"]`

Comment: @TaylorAustin First of all need code refactor,

Step 1 : <div data-testid="custom-element" />

please refer to this if you want which div or something else then you need to add data-testid for that.

Step 2: Add the test case previous you mentioned

Step 3: Run Test Case

Answer (score 1):

```
describe('State is managed correctly', () => {
const { getByTestId } = render(<App />)
const add = getByTestId(`addCount`)
const count = getByTestId(`count`)
const spy = jest.spyOn(add, 'click');
it('count starts at 0', () => {
    expect(count).toHaveTextContent("0")
})


 it('count added, value should be 1', () => {
        add.click();
        expect(count).toHaveTextContent("1") // error count is still 0
        spy.mockRestore();
    })
})
```

Comment: you can't use "fireEvent.click", because, you clickFn is not from props

Comment: i tried to call the function whihc is not props as you said i did only `click` it got worked  thanks