# Unable to find text in document/screen React testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, unit-testing, testing

I'm new to react testing, learning by coding, here i want to click 'cameras' and then under it appears list of cameras, like camera 1, camera 2...

i'm able to find 'cameras' and click it, but then when trying to make sure 'Camera 1' to be in document it wont work and gives this: 'TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Camera 1. This could
be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.'

If have any question just ask me, english is not my mother language so could be mistakes

test code:

```js
import {
  render,
  screen,
  RenderResult,
  cleanup,
  fireEvent,
  getByRole,
  getByDisplayValue,
  getByText,
} from "@testing-library/react";


describe("Testing component", () => {
  test("Testing Camera", async () => {
    const { getByLabelText, getByTestId, getByText, getByRole } = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <CardComponent
          classes={{
            formControl: "",
           
          }}
        />
      </Provider>
    );

    let Cameras = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /cameras/i });
    fireEvent.click(
      Cameras,
      new MouseEvent("click", {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
      })
    );

    const screenText = screen.getByText("Camera 1");
    expect(screenText).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

img:

[image]

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58348882/10824697

Comment: Also try using userEvent instead of fireEvent and see if that makes a difference. https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/

Comment: @SandeepAmarnath ok i did as u said changes:      
     
userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /cameras/i }));
    expect(container).toHaveTextContent(`Camera 1`);
 now it says : Expected element to have text content:
      Camera 1
    Received:
      sites cameras analysers platforms brokers  -----------     it seems clicking 'cameras' did not work because if it worked then there should be Camera 1, as you can see from image

Comment: Have you set up a github repo for this. Can you please share the repo link and I can take a look

Comment: @SandeepAmarnath no idont have but here is 'CardComponent'  <Card data-testid="SelectionCardd" className={classes.selectionCard}>
      <CardContent >
        <Box><Box>
       <SelectionList
action="cameras"
onUpdateClick={(e) => handleUpdateClick(e, CAMERAS)}
 onDeleteClick={(e) => handleDeleteClick(e, CAMERAS)}
onDetailsClick={(e) => handleDetailsClick(e, CAMERAS)}
onAddClick={(e) => handleAddClick(e, CAMERAS)}
classes={classes}
            />
          </Box>
          <Modal open={formOpen}>{renderForm()}</Modal></Box></CardContent></Card>

Comment: @SandeepAmarnath so when that is clicked it opens dropdown like, where 'Camera 1' can be found

Comment: I'll try to setup some code and get back to you

Comment: @SandeepAmarnath if it helps you,  this is SelectionList component: <List
      component="div"
      data-testid="SelectionListt"
    >
      <ListItem
        key={props.action + "-header"}
        button
        data-testid="Listitems"
        onClick={(event) => {
          handleExpandClick(event, itemListCollapseKey);
        }}
      >
        {collapseStates[itemListCollapseKey] ? (
          <ExpandLess />
        ) : (
          <ExpandMore />
    )}{" "}
   <ListItemText >
   {props.action}
  </ListItemText>
  </ListItem>
  {childList}
    </List>
  );
};

Comment: Try importing debug method from render and check if AFTER the click what the output is, it might help determine the issue.

Comment: @alextrastero after the click i should screen.debug()?

Comment: Hey @walee, I have set up some unit tests in my existing code which show and hide the cards. I hope this is very similar to what you are trying. Let me know if this helps https://github.com/sandeep194920/MERN_projects/tree/master/1_show_hide_people

The tests are in `1_show_hide_people/src/App.test.js`